# How to use AND operator in statement

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I am using JDBC in JSP with PostGreSQL.
I want to read all values of a row with the given titel and interpret from a text field but the AND operator doesn't work.

```
// some code
stmt = conn.createStatement();
res = stmt.executeQuery(                                     
                "SELECT * " +
                "FROM album " +
                "WHERE interpret = ? AND titel = ? " +
                "ORDER BY interpret, titel ASC "
                );
//... closte statements, etc.
```

Not I get a syntax exception for AND.
Do you guys have any advices why?

Comment: Are you setting the parameters on the PreparedStatement prior to calling executeQuery()?

Comment: yes but just the two for interpret and titel.
but how do i get the other values for that particular row into stmt.setString(1, ??) if i use a preparedStatement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use bind variables in a statement created with `createStatement`.
[PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) is what you should be working with.

Use:

```
stmt = conn.prepareStatement();
stmt.setString(1, interpretValue); //set the value for the first parameter to interpretValue
stmt.setString(2, titleValue); //second parameter
```

A `PreparedStatement` is the preferred way of executing SQL statements because the statement is precompiled. This can be more efficient than a `Statement`, specially if the same query is executed multiple times.

Comment: Ok thanks for the quick reply, i figured it would be the preparedStatement();
but how do i set the string values for the statement?
i need to get them out of the table right? but how does that work?

Comment: Using one of the setXXX methods. stmt.setString(1, interpretValue);

Comment: yes but how would i use the other values of the row? let's say i have
setString(1, interpret);
setString(2, titel);
setString(3, ???);
and for 3 i want to get a value from the row where interpret and titel are equals the values from the parameters

Comment: For obtaining the result, use the `ResultSet` returned by `executeQuery()`. `res.getString(1)` for the first column, res.getString(2) for the second and so on. If your column types are not strings, use the relevant **setXXX** method.

Comment: the problem is i cannot execute the query without setting all strings. so i want to get those other values of the row that's already existing. it already contains some other values but how do i get them?

Comment: ok nevermind. i found the mistake. i just need to set those 2 values and then execute it query with just those two...simple as that.
but i brought me the right hint so thank you :)
sorry, i'm new to jdbc